# Как взять уникальные значение из списка

Tags: c#, list

Есть два списка

```
var buffList1 = new List<string>(){"1~2~3","13~23~123"}; 
var buffList2 = new List<string>(){"1~3~4","1~3~5"};
```

Чтобы выбрать уникальные значения я делаю так

```
var rezList = buffList1.Except(buffList2).Union(buffList2.Except(buffList1)).ToList();
```

Интересует вариант применения методов `Except` и `Union` по кастомным полям, т.е. допустим есть 2 строки в списках - "1~2~3" и "2~5~3". Нужно сделать Split('~') строки и применить эти два метода к значениям **2** и **5**.

На текущий момент **Except** и **Union** работают по всей строке. Как переопределить их?

Comment: Распарсьте ваши строки в объекты. Примените [кастомный `IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VladD, по моему уже был похожий вопрос

Comment: Я думаю, что по любому придется делать какую-то подготовку строк к сравнению Можно сделать, как сказал VlaD с использованием кастомного сравнителя, иными словами туда заложить твой Split. Но на мой взгляд это не рационально, так как каждый раз будет вызываться Split для коллекции с которой ты сравниваешь. Мне кажется, что проще отдельный метод сделать.

Comment: можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу - получить список уникальных значений, среди элементов, разделенных знаком ~, то должно сработать следующее:

```
var res = buffList1
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split("~"))
    .Union(buffList2
        .SelectMany(s => s.Split("~")))
    .Distinct();
```